# I am facing difficulty in filtering products by category in an e-commerce website in the backend with product controllers in MongoDB/node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

> Product Controller

```
  const products = await Product
    
     .find({ "category.name": "Shoes" })
     .find({ category: { $elemMatch: { name: "T-shirt" } } })
    .populate("category", { name: "Shoes" })
```

**I have tried the above lines of code one at a time but didn't got any results**

> Product Schema

```
    category: {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: "Category",
      required: true,
    }
```

> Category Schema

```
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 32,
      unique: true,
    },

);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the bug. I wasn't filtering it out. I filtered it but there is a catch, it is filtering out page wise.

```
exports.getAllProducts = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  let sortBy = req.query.sortBy ? req.query.sortBy : "createdAt";
  let sortByOrder = req.query.sortByOrder ? req.query.sortByOrder : "desc";
  const categoryName = req.query.categoryName ? req.query.categoryName : "";
  const page = Number(req.query.pageNumber) || 1;
  const pageSize = 5;

  const keyword = req.query.keyword
    ? {
        $or: [
          { name: { $regex: req.query.keyword, $options: "i" } },
          { description: { $regex: req.query.keyword, $options: "i" } },
        ],
      }
    : {};

  let count = await Product.countDocuments({ ...keyword });
  await Product.find({ ...keyword })
    .select("-photo")
    .populate({
      path: "category",
      match: {
        name: "Jacket",
      },
    })
    .sort([[sortBy, sortByOrder]])
    .limit(pageSize)
    .skip(pageSize * (page - 1));
  const products = products
    .filter(function (product) {
      return product.category;
    })
    .exec(err, products, (page = Number(req.query.pageNumber) || 1), pages);

  if (err) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: "NO Product FOUND!",
    });
  }

  res.json({
    products,
    page,
    pages: Math.ceil(count / pageSize),
  });
});
```